# Непонятка с .getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

Проблема вот в чем, пытался изобрести велосипед, ну, так сказать, повторить ЯваСкрипт, изобрел, он работал, потом перестал, не могу понять, в чем проблема (на счет кросс-браузерности не заморачивался, так что не вините, важно, хотя бы чтоб заработало). Вот код.

Вот что я хотел изобрести (Jquery); этот код работает...

```
$('img').each(function() {
    if($(this).width()>500)
        $(this).fadeOut(4000);
})
```

А вот и сам ЯваСкрипт

```
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    k = 0,
    arr = new Array(),
    i, n;

for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    if (obj[i].width > 500) {
        arr[k] = obj[i];
        k++;
    }

n = k;
k = 1;

function opacity_() {
    if (k <= 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i].style.opacity = k;
        k -= 0.004;
    }
}

opacity_();

var id = setInterval(function () {
    opacity_();
}, 10);
```

говорит, что у `obj.length = 0`, вопрос по идее легкий, но чего-то я туплю; )) изображения в документе есть, у которых `width=960px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что код выполняется после того, как DOM была построена? Так как на странице есть большие картинки, то есть вероятность, что они не успевают загрузиться.

Comment: Точняк, ДОМ дерево ведь не построено, спасибо =)

Comment: А как сделать аналог jQuery `$(function() { }` в яваскрипт?

Comment: window.onload = function(){} или setTimeout(function(){}, 0), хотя насчет второго варианта я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо, а я искал в document.onload ...)

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, скрипт стоит ДО изображений.

Comment: Да, да, до изображений.